# How do I inject httpClient into an instantiated service?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am instantiating MyService in app.module.ts, and providing it throughout my code.

However, I want MyService to use httpClient, and I am unable to angular-idiomatically instantiate httpClient to pass as a parameter to MyService. I'm not sure what the right way to access httpClient in MyService is.

I've looked at instantiating httpClient directly and then passing it as a parameter to my service. However it seems this creates a circular dependency. I have also tried messing with Injectors but this is specifically advised against by the Angular team apparently. I strongly feel I am missing something simple.

app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    ...
    httpClientModule
    ...
],

function MainServiceFactory() {
    return new MyService();
}
...
providers: [{
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: MainServiceFactory
}],
...
```

MyService.ts

```
...
constructor(private http : HttpClient) {
    ...
}
```

Without instantiation and passing as parameter of httpClient: I get an "error in app.module.ts, expected 1 argument", naturally!
With instantiation I break angular recommendations.

**Edit:**
I had neglected to specify that I did import the httpClientModule

Comment: Have you considered just including the HttpClientModule? Your service factory doesn't actually match the constructor signature of the service, so there's no rational basis to expect that it might work.

Comment: See the first section of the [HttpClient Documentation - Setup](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup) => `Before you can use the HttpClient, you need to import the Angular HttpClientModule. Most apps do so in the root AppModule.....`

Comment: Once you do that then learn how to register your service type with angular. There is no reason to create a custom factory in this case. If you were to follow along with the tutorial or documentation on https://angular.io this would be one of the things covered early on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone say, you have to import `HttpClientModule`

Looking to your code, I think you are trying to deal with `angular's dependency injection`:

I did an example in the stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqvlv7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Where I define an abstract class to behave like an interface, and then `my.service` implements this interface.

Inside the app.module, I provide the 'interface' using `my-service` class. After all this, you can inject the 'interface' in the component (in this link, hello.component.ts)

The `HttpClient` is injected only in `my-service` and there is no problem at all.

I hope it helps you to understand it better.

Comment: It doesn't work for Angular 12. I am geting NullInjectorError: No provider for MyService.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Angular API](https://angular.io/api/core/FactoryProvider) the FactoryProvider has an optional `deps` field inherited from core/FactorySansProvider. This field is an array where you can put dependencies for your factory. The only needed changes are:

```
function MainServiceFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new MyService(http);
}

providers: [{
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: MainServiceFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient]
}],
```

Here a reference to Angular [dependency providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers). The documentation also says that the `useFactory` should be used to evaluate run time dependencies and not static ones, but I guess that you have multiple options in your real code.